# Two conditions in While with Buffered reader

Tags: java, while-loop, bufferedreader

This is my first post. I am a beginner to Java.

I am trying to read a text file using BufferedReader. What I want to do is, it should only read lines starting with 'U' (I have lines starting with '#' which I want to ignore).

```
    String line = "";

    // reader is BufferedReader
    while (((line = reader.readLine()) != null) && (line.charAt(0) == 'U')) { // make sure only lines starting with 'U' are read
        Variant variant = new Variant(line);
        variants.add(variant); // list of Variant objects
    }
```

When I execute this, I get an empty list as output.

But when I try this,

```
    String line = "";

    // reader is BufferedReader
    while (((line = reader.readLine()) != null) ) { // make sure only lines starting with 'U' are read
        System.out.println("Char at 0: " + line.charAt(0));
        Variant variant = new Variant(line);
        variants.add(variant); // list of Variant objects
    }
```

Sure enough, it prints 'U' on the screen but I also get lines which don't start with 'U' as output.

Why is this happening? Is it because I am trying to assign some value to 'line' and checking it against some condition in the same expression ?

Comment: Have you tried to use this `(line.charAt(0) == 'U')` as a separate condition inside the loop ?? like this :
`if(line.charAt(0) == 'U'){Variant variant = new Variant(line);
        variants.add(variant); }`

Comment: Don't use `charAt` to test if it starts with "`U`" use `startsWith` instead otherwise you will get an `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` in case you have an empty line

Comment: I tried this. I get StringIndexOutOfBounds exception. But @Elliott's answer works fine. Why is this ? Am I doing something wrong somewhere else outside the block of code I provided in the question ?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto thanks !! I was getting that exception. I just checked, there's an empty line all the way down at the end of the file (pretty long file). That seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try and put ***all*** of the logic in your `while` condition. Also, you could use `String.startsWith(String)` (or `charAt(0)` if you really prefer); but something like,

```
String line;
// reader is BufferedReader
while (((line = reader.readLine()) != null)) {
    if (line.startsWith("#")) {
        continue;
    } else if (line.startsWith("U")) {
        Variant variant = new Variant(line);
        variants.add(variant); // list of Variant objects
    }
}
```

**or**

```
String line;
// reader is BufferedReader
while (((line = reader.readLine()) != null)) {
    if (line.startsWith("U")) {
        Variant variant = new Variant(line);
        variants.add(variant); // list of Variant objects
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! But line.charAt(0) == 'U' doesn't work. I get StringIndexOutOfBounds exception.

Comment: @retrazil `if (!line.isEmpty() && line.charAt(0) == 'U')` (because `""` doesn't have a first character).

Comment: Yup!! That was exactly my problem. I didn't add !line.isEmpty() and there was an empty line at the end of the file. I have accepted your answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

when you are checking the first char of a line , if it is not 'U' then the condition of the while loop is false , so your program doesn't see the other lines , you can do this instead :

```
String line = "";
// reader is BufferedReader
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if(line.charAt(0) != 'U') continue;
    Variant variant = new Variant(line);
    variants.add(variant); // list of Variant objects
}
```

Comment: Be aware that this will cause an `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` in case of an empty line.